# Determining which rule NIntegrate selects automatically

Tags: numerical-integration

I need to numerically integrate a highly oscillatory function over the semi-infinite domain $(0,\infty)$:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2(x) \sin^2(1000 x)}{x^{5/2}}\mathrm dx$$

Since the Levin rule (which was recently added to *Mathematica*, starting in version 8) was developed specifically for oscillatory integrals such as this, I thought I'd try it:

```
ans = NIntegrate[Sin[x]^2 Sin[1000 x]^2/x^(5/2), {x, 0, Infinity}, 
                 Method -> {"LevinRule"}, PrecisionGoal -> 8, MaxRecursion -> 30]
```

Using an exact solution for this integral, I can confirm the relative accuracy of the *Mathematica* result is $1 \times 10^{-11}$, and moreover the calculation is very quick. At first, this led me to believe that Levin's method works great for this problem, but...

It turns out that *Mathematica* must be automatically switching to non-oscillatory rule behind the scenes, because forcing it not to do so gives a very poor result:

```
ans = NIntegrate[Sin[x]^2 Sin[1000 x]^2/x^(5/2), {x, 0, Infinity},  
                 Method -> {"LevinRule", "MethodSwitching" -> False},
                 PrecisionGoal -> 8, MaxRecursion -> 30]
```

> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy
>   after 30 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {0.}. NIntegrate
>   obtained -3497.5 and 3510.0321785369356` for the integral and error
>   estimates. >>

Is there any way to find out which alternative non-oscillatory rule *Mathematica* is automatically selecting? I've tried to guess which rule is being used by manually specifying few rules but the results I've obtained with other rules are inaccurate, slow, or both:

```
ans = NIntegrate[(Sin[x])^2 (Sin[1000 x])^2/x^(5/2), {x, 0, Infinity}, 
                 Method -> "ClenshawCurtisRule", AccuracyGoal -> 8, MaxRecursion -> 30]
```

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly;
>   suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is
>   0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small. >>
>
> NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has
>   increased more than 400 times. The global error is expected to
>   decrease monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations.
>   Suspect one of the following: the working precision is insufficient
>   for the specified precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory
>   or it is not a (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value of the
>   integral is 0. Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option
>   MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent numerical integration.
>   NIntegrate obtained 0.000013202052151832003` and
>   1.0480362255168103`*^-6 for the integral and error estimates. >>

I'd like to know what rule *Mathematica* is using so that I can try adjusting options for the best performance possible. I need to calculate this integral several hundred thousand times, as the innermost integral of a nested double integration. Furthermore, when it comes to publishing my results, I would like to be able to state the integration strategy that was actually used, rather than "*Mathematica* knew how to handle it".

Comment: Why not use, say, `"ExtrapolatingOscillatory"` or `"DoubleExponentialOscillatory"` instead, since your oscillatory integral is over $[0,\infty)$ anyway?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! There are a few reasons I didn't use "ExtrapolatingOscillatory" or "DoubleExponentialOscillatory" from the start. First, I will need to integrate this function over both finite intervals [0,a] as well as semi-infinite intervals [a,infinity], with a>0. Second, I had previously implemented both of these rules from scratch in IDL and found that both require too much computation time when the frequency (1000 in the example I show here) increases. For example, to compute

Comment: BTW: in fact, the default method used by `NIntegrate[]` for "nice" integrals is `"GlobalAdaptive"`; as you've noticed, it is the method being used instead of `"LevinRule"`, somewhat sneakily...

Comment: Sorry--my previous comment was truncated. I didn't opt for the "ExtrapolatingOscillatory" or "DoubleExponentialOscillatory" rules because I will need to integrate this function over both finite intervals [0,a] as well as semi-infinite intervals [a,infinity]. Also, computation time for these rules should scale with frequency (w=1000 in the example I show) but not so for Levin.  Nevertheless, having just tried it, I see that both the "ExtrapolatingOscillatory" and "DoubleExponentialOscillatory" rules in Mathematica do give fast and accurate results even for w=100,000.

Comment: Well, as you've seen, `"LevinRule"` can be more efficient than the other two oscillatory methods, but it is rather finicky, and you need to do some fiddling sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll experiment some more with the options for LevinRule, and hopefully Mathematica won't override my choices without letting me know :-)

Comment: In particular, you might be interested in the `ExcludedForms` option, if you choose the strategy of only considering the more oscillatory `Sin[1000 x]`, while ignoring `Sin[x]`. If you take a look at the advanced documentation, there is also a pointer to the undocumented function ``NIntegrate`LevinIntegrandReduce[]``, which might help you in exploring how to properly set options.

Comment: ans = 
 NIntegrate[Sin[x]^2 Sin[1000 x]^2/x^2.5, {x, 0, Infinity}, 
  Method -> {"LevinRule", "MethodSwitching" -> False, 
    "Kernel" -> Sin[1000 x]^2, "Points" -> 5}, PrecisionGoal -> 8]

During evaluation of In[36]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {0.}. NIntegrate obtained 1.1675453364639328` and 0.00030762526309975006` for the integral and error estimates. >>

Out[36]= 1.16754533646

Comment: Thanks. Surprisingly, NIntegrate complains about insufficient recursive bisections even when "MethodSwitching" is False. Does this mean NIntegrate is again falling back on GlobalAdaptive, or is the singularity at 0 causing a problem with Levin's collocation?

    ans =  NIntegrate[Sin[x]^2 Sin[1000 x]^2/x^2.5, {x, 0, Infinity},  Method -> {"LevinRule", "MethodSwitching" -> False, "Kernel" -> Sin[1000 x]^2, "Points" -> 5}, PrecisionGoal -> 8]

During evaluation of In[36]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {0.}.

Answer (score 41):

This question comes up often enough. See this discussion at [community.wolfram.com](http://community.wolfram.com) : [Integration method used in NIntegrate](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/314124) , and the notebook [Finding the applied NIntegrate methods](http://community.wolfram.com/groups?p_auth=nbRdQI9w&p_p_id=19&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=exclusive&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_pos=1&p_p_col_count=3&_19_struts_action=%2Fmessage_boards%2Fget_message_attachment&_19_messageId=370695&_19_attachment=Finding%20the%20applied%20NIntegrate%20methods.nb) attached to my second response in the discussion.

That notebook contains examples of usage of the undocumented function `NIntegrateSamplingPoints` and `NIntegrate`'s option `IntegrationMonitor`.

**The integral in the question**

For the integral in the question with `NIntegrateSamplingPoints` we get kind of a boring picture because of the infinite region. Taking logs of the sampling points might be more informative:

```
Needs["Integration`NIntegrateUtilities`"]

gr = NIntegrateSamplingPoints@
   NIntegrate[Sin[x]^2 Sin[1000 x]^2/x^(5/2), {x, 0, Infinity}, 
    Method -> {"LevinRule", 
      Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 11}}];

Graphics[gr[[1]] /. 
  Point[{x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ}] :> 
   Point[{Log[10, x + 10^-12], y}], Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"lg(sampling points)", "evaluation order"}, AspectRatio -> 1/1.5]
```

[image]

The plot shows the order of evaluation of the sampling points.

Using `IntegrationMonitor` we can see the application of the integrand over the regions derived with the `LevinRule` method:

```
t = Reap[NIntegrate[Sin[x]^2 Sin[1000 x]^2/x^(5/2), {x, 0, Infinity}, 
    Method -> {"LevinRule", 
      Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 11}}, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 1.5, 
    IntegrationMonitor -> (Sow[
        Map[{#1@"Integrand", #1@"Boundaries", #1@"Integral", #1@
            "Error"} &, #1]] &)]];
res = t[[1]];
t = t[[2, 1]];
t
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

*(I have had the code below for some time, but I have been hesitant to share it because of several concerns. It is somewhat hard to interpret its results and coming up with it does require some internal knowledge of NIntegrate's development. After dedicated discussions with/about the NIntegrate method tracing code at [WTC 2015](http://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2015/) it seems that it is better to show and describe it.)*

We can trace `NIntegrate`'s method initialization by manipulating the top level initialization function implementations. The basic idea is to take the down values and up values of the initialization functions of NIntegrate's methods that have the form

```
Block[{v___}, b_CompoundExpression]
```

and replace them with

```
Block[{res = Block[{v}, b]}, Print[res]; res]
```

When an `NIntegrate` command is executed we will see a printed trace of the methods that are initialized.

Here is the tracing code:

```
symbNames = Names["NIntegrate`*"];
symbNames = 
  Append[Pick[symbNames, 
    StringMatchQ[
     symbNames, (__ ~~ "Rule") | (__ ~~ 
        "Global" | "Local" | "MonteCarlo" | "Principal" | "Levin" | 
         "Osc" ~~ ___)]], "NIntegrate`AutomaticStrategy"];
symbs = ToExpression[#] & /@ symbNames;
dvs = DownValues /@ symbs;
uvs = UpValues /@ symbs;
Unprotect /@ symbs;
dvsNew = MapThread[
   With[{s = #2},
     DownValues[s] = 
      ReplaceAll[#1, 
       HoldPattern[
         a_ :> b___] :> (a :> (Print["DownValue call for: ", 
            Style[s, Red]]; b))]] &, {dvs, symbs, symbNames}];
uvsNew = MapThread[
   With[{s = #2},
     UpValues[s] =
      ReplaceAll[#1,
       HoldPattern[Block[vars_, CompoundExpression[b___]]] :>
        Block[{res = Block[vars, CompoundExpression[b]]}, 
         Print["UpValue call for: ", Style[s, Blue], 
          Style[" ::\n", Blue], res]; res]
       ]
     ] &, {uvs, symbs, symbNames}];
```

In that code using `Pick` I have reduced the number of `NIntegrate` context symbols being traced. Of course, if it is desired, the down/up values of the full list of the `NIntegrate` context symbols can be manipulated for tracing.

Let us look at tracing examples.

Here is a numerical integration computation with an automatically selected method:

[image]

The basic objects of `NIntegrate` are integration regions. Each region has its own integration function and integration rule. In order to interpret the printed trace it is helpful to know that `NIntegrate` uses the [software design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) [Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), [Composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern), [Decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), and others.

`NIntegrate`'s symbolic pre-processors are using Decorator, and we can see in the trace that the outcome of AutomaticStrategy are pre-processor symbols wrapped around the method "GlobalAdaptive". The method "GlobalAdaptive" uses a Gauss-Kronrod rule, which after its initialization is treated as a general rule. (I.e. a list of abscissas, integral estimate weights, and approximation error weights.)

The method GlobalAdaptive is going to be directly used if symbolic processing is prevented:

[image]

Here is a numerical integration computation with a specifically selected pre-processing method:

[image]

**UPDATE 2 (`IntegrationMonitor` methods)**

*(Thanks to [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) for prompting these explanations.)*

Each integration strategy of `NIntegrate` creates and manipulates a collection of integration regions. Each integration region can have its own integrand and/or integration rule. `NIntegrate`'s main integration strategy "GlobalAdaptive" keeps the integration regions in a heap according to their error. The sum of the integral estimates of all regions make the global integral estimate. The sum of the integral errors make the global error. If the global error is larger than the desired tollerance "GlobalAdaptive" splits the region with the largest error estimate into two regions and applies the integration rule. If too many splittings have been done then a singularity handler is applied over the last region split.

At each step of an integration strategy the option `IntegrationMonitor` obtains as an argument the list of integration regions used in that step. Below is a table that shows methods that can be applied to each integration region in that list.

[image]

And here is (another) example of the application of those methods:

```
iRegionMethods = {"Axis", "Boundaries", "Dimension", "Error", 
  "GetRule", "Integral", "Integrand", "WorkingPrecision"}; res = 
 Reap@NIntegrate[x^2 y^2, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 2}, PrecisionGoal -> 1.1, 
   Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo", 
   IntegrationMonitor :> 
    Function[{iregs}, 
     Sow[Association /@ 
       Transpose[
        Map[Thread[# -> Through[iregs[#]]] &, iRegionMethods]]]]];
Dataset[Flatten[res[[2]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: It seems you know how to work with ``Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction``. Please consider answering the [dedicated question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43513/280) or improving my CW answer in that thread. It is currently unclear how to use the fourth argument of `CreateNumericalFunction` as well as options `"ErrorReturn"`, `"SampleArgument"` and `Message`. As you can see, the question is highly appreciated by the community.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I am sorry I don't think I can contribute more to that post. (And my knowledge on that function seems to be fairly outdated...)

Comment: It's too bad I can't give another +1. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @J.M. Thanks, that is nice to hear!

Comment: Note that the methods available in `IntegrationMonitor` appear to be `{"Axis", "Boundaries", "Dimension", "Error", "GetReuseValues", "GetRule", "GetSamplingPoints", "GetValues", "Integral", "Integrand", "NumericalFunction", "OriginalBoundaries", "Properties", "WorkingPrecision"}`.

Comment: @AntonAntonov I'm sure you knew that, but I thought I'd it record for others who consult this Q&A.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That is a good idea! I will edit the answer to include those methods. (I think there are several more methods and properties like "GetLevel" and "GetScale", but they are more esoteric, i.e. your list is fairly complete.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Could you tell me how to find these methods in `IntegrationMonitor`?

Comment: @luyuwuli Probably this way: `Reap[NIntegrate[x, {x, 0, 1},   IntegrationMonitor :> (Sow[Map[{#1@"Methods"} &, #1]] &)]]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Great! Thanks a lot:)

Comment: This seems to catch more strategies in the current version of *Mma*: ``symbNames = Join[ Pick[symbNames, StringMatchQ[symbNames, (__ ~~ "Rule")]], Pick[symbNames, NIntegrate`IntegrationStrategyQ /@ StringSplit[symbNames, "`"][[All, 2]]]]``

Comment: The notebook cannot be accessed anymore it seems. Is it possible to make it available again?

Comment: @Brownian_Motion Please remind me -- which notebook, where? Somewhere in Community?

Comment: @AntonAntonov the notebook linked in the reply above: "Finding the applied NIntegrate methods ". The link seems not to be working.

Comment: @Brownian_Motion Thanks! I will add tomorrow that notebook in this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/antononcube/NIntegrateTheMissingManual-book).

Answer (score 19):

As you may know, the backup non-oscillatory rule is controlled by the `Method` sub-option of `"LevinRule", [documented here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html#32844337). You can use it like this:

```
In[60]:= NIntegrate[Sin[x]^2 Sin[1000 x]^2/x^(5/2), {x, 0, Infinity}, 
 Method -> {"LevinRule", 
   Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 11}}]

Out[60]= 1.16762
```

With this, you can try to tune for performance.

In your example, the default setting `Method -> Automatic` is effectively equivalent to `Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 5}`. There is no *documented* method to determine this, but you can more or less verify it by doing something naughty like:

```
In[61]:= Block[{NIntegrate`GaussKronrodRuleData = (Print[{##}]; 
     Abort[]) &}, 
 NIntegrate[Sin[x]^2 Sin[1000 x]^2/x^(5/2), {x, 0, Infinity}, 
  Method -> {"LevinRule"}, PrecisionGoal -> 8, MaxRecursion -> 30]]

During evaluation of In[61]:= {5,MachinePrecision}

Out[61]= $Aborted
```