# What method does NIntegrate use by default?

Tags: numerical-integration, implementation-details

There is a variety of algorithms for performing numerical integration (See [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration)). What method does [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html) use by default?

I looked at the documentation page and I saw that the function `NIntegrate` can use a ton of different algorithms, but I couldn't find which one is used by default. Where can I find this info?

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html Maybe?

Comment: and here http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html I "think" they select the rules "Automatically".

Comment: It is all here [SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html)

Comment: The docs @Chen linked to seem to tell me that `NIntegrate[]` uses `"GlobalAdaptive"` as the integration *strategy*, with the Gauss-Kronrod rule as the integration *rule*. [Here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26401) is a related question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the answer is in the links -- just to demonstrate or validate what it says:

```
 First@Last@
    Reap@NIntegrate[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[x], 
          MaxRecursion -> 0, Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"]
 xi=First@Last@
    Reap@NIntegrate[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[x], 
          MaxRecursion -> 0]
```

> {0.00795732, 0.0469101, 0.122917, 0.230765, 0.360185, 0.5, 0.639815, 
>   0.769235, 0.877083, 0.95309, 0.992043}
>
> {0.00795732, 0.0469101, 0.122917, 0.230765, 0.360185, 0.5, 0.639815, 
>   0.769235, 0.877083, 0.95309, 0.992043}

the default uses the same evaluation points as the `"GaussKronrodRule"` method.

You can then pull out the weights like this:

```
 w=(f[x_?NumericQ] := Boole[x == #];
    Quiet@NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 0]) & /@ xi
```

> {0.021291, 0.0576167, 0.0934004, 0.12052, 0.136425, 0.141494, 
>   0.136425, 0.12052, 0.0934004, 0.0576167, 0.021291}

and show they are of course the same whether you specify `"GaussKronrodRule"` or nothing.

for completeness, just to show the weight extraction is correct:

```
 {w.Sin[xi] , NIntegrate[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}]}
 SameQ @@ %
```

> {0.459698, 0.459698}
>
> True

Finally note, even with `MaxRecursions->0` the automatic method can change, for example if it detects an oscilatory function:

```
 First@Last@Reap@NIntegrate[Sin[4 x], {x, 0, 1}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[x], 
      MaxRecursion -> 0]
```

> {1., 0.996057, 0.984292, 0.964888, 0.938153, 0.904508, 0.864484, 
>   0.818712, 0.767913, 0.71289, 0.654508, 0.593691, 0.531395, 0.468605, 
>   0.406309, 0.345492, 0.28711, 0.232087, 0.181288, 0.135516, 0.0954915, 
>   0.0618467, 0.0351118, 0.0157084, 0.00394265, 0.}