# Convergence data for Monte Carlo NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, random

I am using `NIntegrate` with `Method -> "MonteCarlo"` to evaluate a high dimensional integral. Is there a way I can obtain a list containing *Mathematica*'s successive estimates for the integral? I would like to see a plot showing the convergence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the undocumented [`IntegrationMonitor`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26401/determining-which-rule-nintegrate-selects-automatically/96663#96663):

```
{val, {vals}} = 
 Reap@NIntegrate[x y^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PrecisionGoal -> 2,
   Method -> "MonteCarlo",
   IntegrationMonitor :> ((Sow[Total@Through[#["Integral"]]]) &)]
(*
  {0.165268, {{0.186623, 0.172189, 0.168129, 0.166339, 0.165429, 
     0.16988, 0.173145, 0.171675, 0.173355, 0.177199, 0.175892, 
     0.176102, 0.176696, 0.175119, 0.173314, 0.172074, 0.172378, 
     0.173556, 0.172886, 0.173371, 0.171839, 0.172351, 0.171481, 
     ...,
     0.165933, 0.165739, 0.165553, 0.165592, 0.165477, 0.165581, 
     0.165412, 0.165332, 0.165484, 0.165209, 0.165268}}}
*)

ListPlot@vals
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Yes... try using  `EvaluationMonitor`

```
ListPlot[Reap[
   NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[x y z], {x, 0,1}, {y, 0,1}, {z, 0,1},
    EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[x]]][[2, 1]], PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: This command plots the $x$-coordinates of the sampling points.

Comment: Is there a way to sow the actual integrand rather than just the x-coordinates (without computing the integrand a second time for each x-coordinate, since that would be inefficient as my integrand is computationally expensive)?