# How is N[Mean[distribution]] evaluated?

Tags: numerics, probability-or-statistics, distributions, implementation-details

Particularly when applied to calculating the (population) mean of a (continuous univariate) random variable, as in

```
dist2alt = 
 TransformedDistribution[Sqrt[4]*Sqrt[x], 
  x \[Distributed] NoncentralFRatioDistribution[5, 4, 0, 7.2]]

N[Mean[dist2alt]]
(* 1.30371 *)
```

, what are the (numerical) methods used internally by the sentence `N`?

Does *Mathematica* provide any details about the concrete (numerical) methods used in a concrete execution of `N`, the number of iterations needed, etc.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`Mean`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mean.html) doc page says,

> `Mean[dist]` is equivalent to `Expectation[x,x\[Distributed]dist]`.

The [`Expectation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Expectation.html) doc page says,

> `N[Expectation[...]]` calls `NExpectation` for expectations that cannot be done symbolically.

[`NExpectation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NExpectation.html) can use [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html), whose options can be specified through `Method`.

---

When you use `Mean`, the default (automatic) settings will be used. If you need more control, use the equivalent `NExpectation`. If you need control over how `NExpectation` calls `NIntegrate`, use its `Method` option.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to know what method is `NIntegrate` using in a given computation? (the documentation says that the default option is `Automatic`, which is like "choose the best method for this concrete case")

The point is that I am able to give numerical results to some computations of means and variances using `N`, but I should be able to give a detailed way to reproduce them.

Comment: @Vicent https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26401/12

Comment: @Vicent I'd say that, in general, the most important thing is not to give steps to reproduce a certain numerical result precisely. It is more important to be able to carry out the calculation fully manually (not necessarily to do all steps), and through this understanding decide if a reasonably competent person can be expected to reproduce your calculations *using any tool* (not necessarily Mathematica). If there are any steps which seem particularly difficult, discuss those steps only.  In addition, check all results returned by Mathematica (or whatever system you are using) in some way.

Comment: All systems have bugs, and sometimes give wrong results, even for calculations which should be simple.  You can look at your integrand and see if it's simple, then try increasing the precision and integration points in NIntegrate and see if the result is stable.

Comment: After checking out the link you provided (very interesting!),it seems clear to me that it is nearly impossible trying to explain or reproduce in a detailed way the method used by Mathematica to numerically calculate a given mean or variance, apart from "applying a combination of numerical methods".

Now I think I am going to focus on finding an approximation that is accurate enough and easy to implement by other researchers. What do you think?

Comment: @Vicent If you just need reproducibility, you do not need to find out what `Automatic` does. You simply need to set a method you understand explicitly (and not let Mathematica choose a method automatically).   See `NIntegrate` doc page and here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateOverview.html