# Why do I get "PrincipalValue cannot work with the specified exclusions" when feeding a list to a function?

Tags: numerical-integration, singularity

I have the following test function which I want to evaluate at various points from $x=0$ to $5$:

$f(x) = \int^{20}_{1}\frac{1}{x-y} dy$

There's clearly a singularity here in the integral at $x=y$, which is why in the code sample below I specified the principal value method & exclusion.

```
TestList = Range[0, 5, 0.5]
TestFunc[x_] :=  NIntegrate[1/(x - y), {y, 1, 20}, Method -> "PrincipalValue", Exclusions -> {x == y}]
```

Mathematica is able to evaluate TestFunc at various points, e.g. if I input

```
TestFunc[2]
```

I get $-2.89037$, which is correct ($\int^{20}_{1}\frac{1}{2-y} dy=-\mathrm{ln}(18)= -2.89037$). However if I input the list

```
TestFunc[TestList]
```

Mathematica refuses to evaluate, returning the error

```
NIntegrate::pvexeq: PrincipalValue cannot work with the specified exclusions.
```

Why? Strictly, when I evaluate TestFunc[2], I get this warning message

```
NIntegrate::izero: Integral and error estimates are 0 on all integration subregions. Try increasing the value of the MinRecursion option. If value of integral may be 0, specify a finite value for the AccuracyGoal option."
```

However the result is still accurate, and increasing MinRecursion to 80 as well as MaxRecursion to 90 doesn't change anything.

Comment: You are feeding the entire list to the `Exclusions` option in a single `Integrate` command. Either use `Map` (`/@`): `TestFunc /@ TestList` or define your function as `Listable`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interpreting the OP's example as an [MWE](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2126/what-do-we-mean-by-a-self-contained-minimal-working-example) and not the actual problem, there are three issues: (1) evaluating the integral for a list of test values; (2) the integral and error being zero; and (3) the example integral being divergent even in the principal value sense if the singularity is at an endpoint of the interval of integration.

**Listability**

The easiest way to make `testFunc` operate on a list of input values is to give it the attribute `Listable`.

```
testList = Range[0, 5, 0.5];
ClearAll[testFunc];
SetAttributes[testFunc, Listable];
testFunc[x_] := 
 NIntegrate[1/(x - y), {y, 1, 20}, Method -> "PrincipalValue", 
  Exclusions -> {x == y}, AccuracyGoal -> 100];
```

The following gives some errors because `x == 1` is in `testList` and the principal value does not exist for it (3rd entry).

```
testFunc[testList]
(*
{-2.99573, -3.66356, -39.0857, -3.61092, -2.89037, -2.45674, 
 -2.14007, -1.88707, -1.67398, -1.48808, -1.32176}
*)
```

**Zero integrals**

Integrals that are zero cause an error in the error norm `NIntegrate` uses by default and the `NIntegrate::izero` warning message to be issued.

```
NIntegrate[0., {x, 0, 1}]
```

> NIntegrate::izero: Integral and error estimates are 0 on all integration subregions....If value of integral may be 0, specify a finite value for the AccuracyGoal option.

```
(*  0.  *)
```

For an integral that is zero, the solution is to set a finite value for `AccuracyGoal` as in `testFunc[]` above.
The default setting is `AccuracyGoal -> Infinity`, and in that case `NIntegrate` uses only relative error in determining sufficient convergence. However, the relative error when the estimate and absolute error estimate are both zero is undefined.  Setting a finite value for `AccuracyGoal` indicates how close to zero the estimate has to be for a result of zero to be considered acceptable.  A result of zero for both the integral and error might occur because underflow occurred at all sampling points, or the sampling points accidentally all landed on roots of the integrand, and perhaps other rare possibilities.

Here is an example of a positive integral and integrand that evaluates to zero:

```
NIntegrate[Exp[-1000 (Exp[1000 (x - Sqrt[2.])^2] - 1)], {x, 0, 2}]
```

> NIntegrate::izero: Integral and error estimates are 0 on all integration subregions. Try increasing the value of the MinRecursion option....

```
(*  0.  *)

NIntegrate[Exp[-1000 (Exp[1000 (x - Sqrt[2])^2] - 1)], {x, 0, Sqrt[2], 2}]
(*  0.000885895  *)
```

Instead of using `MinRecursion` as suggested, I manually subdivided the interval at a point `x == Sqrt[2]` where the function does not underflow to zero.  (Setting a finite value for `AccuracyGoal` in the first integral, even as high as `AccuracyGoal -> 100` makes the warning go away but still returns the inaccurate value of `0.`)
Further, the second, positive result is still inaccurate.  Increasing `MinRecursion` helps.  Increasing `WorkingPrecision` can also help with underflow, but in this case, one also has to raise `MaxRecursion`:

```
NIntegrate[[-1000 (Exp[1000 (x - Sqrt[2])^2] - 1)], {x, 0, Sqrt[2], 2}, 
 MinRecursion -> 2]
(*  0.00177179  *)

NIntegrate[Exp[-1000 (Exp[1000 (x - Sqrt[2])^2] - 1)], {x, 0, 2}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
(*  0.00177179007867237284978305329244440725705339189727922053943991469...  *)
```

**Why does the OP's integral evaluate to zero? It does not even come close to underflowing!**

This has to do with how the `"PrincipalValue"` method is implemented.  It takes a symmetric subinterval around each singularity, divides it at the singularity, reflects the integrand around the singularity and adds.  If the integral converges in the principal value sense, the singularities will cancel and there will be a finite residual integral.  In the OP's case, it is zero.  For $x=2$ in the OP's case, the transformation is as follows:
$$
\int_{3/2}^{5/2} {dy \over 2-y} =
 \int_{3/2}^{2}  {dy \over 2-y} + 
  \int_{2}^{5/2} {dy \over 2-y} =
 \int_0^{1/2}    {du \over u} +
  \int_0^{1/2}  -{du \over u} =
 \int_0^{1/2}     0\; dy \,,
$$
where the first substitution is $2 - y = u$ and the second substitution is $2 - y = -u$.

We can examine the setup `NIntegrate` uses with [`IntegrationMonitor`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26401/determining-which-rule-nintegrate-selects-automatically/96663#96663):

```
Quiet@Reap[       (* ignore error messages *)
   Block[{x = 2},
    NIntegrate[1/(x - y), {y, 1, 20}, Method -> "PrincipalValue", 
     Exclusions -> {x == y}, MaxRecursion -> 0,
     IntegrationMonitor -> (Sow[
         Map[{#1["Integrand"]["FunctionExpression"], #1@
             "Boundaries", #1@"Integral", #1@"Error"} &, #1]] &)]
    ]
   ][[-1, -1]]

(* integrand     interval      integral est.  error est.
  {{{1/(2 - y),  {{1, 1.5}},    0.693147,     2.27069*10^-8}},
   {{1/(2 - y),  {{2.5, 20}},  -3.58393,      0.132922}},
   {{0,          {{0, 0.5}},    0.,           0.}}}
*)
```

The third entry is the principal value sub-integral.

Comment: Thanks for answer, very helpful. Question: what does MWE stand for?

Comment: @Allure MWE = minimal working example. Users are encouraged to post the simplest code that illustrates the problem instead of a large complicated mess of code, most of which has nothing to do with the issue.

Answer (score 3):

This integral can be calculated exactly

```
TestList = Range[0, 5, 1/2];
    TestFunc[x_List] := Integrate[1/(x - y), {y, 1, 20}, PrincipalValue -> True]
    TestFunc[TestList]
    {-Log[20], -Log[39], -\[Infinity], -Log[37], -Log[18], -Log[35/
       3], -Log[17/2], -Log[33/5], -Log[16/3], -Log[31/7], -Log[15/4]}
```