# I am failing to verify an analytical integral with Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to use Mathematica to check an integral from a book, and cannot get it done. The book talks about a spherically symmetric mass distribution in $R^3$ of the form

$\rho(r)=r^{-\gamma}, \gamma<3$

and it goes on by stating that the Newtonian potential to that distribution is given by

$\phi(r) = 4π\ln r + \mathrm{const.}, \gamma=2$

and

$\phi(r) = \frac{4π}{(2-\gamma)(3-\gamma)}r^{2-\gamma}+\mathrm{const.}, \gamma\neq2$ .

(There are a couple more constants in the book which I set to 1 here for simplicity.)

I wanted to verify this by directly evaluating the integral for the potential

$\phi(\mathbf x) =
-\int_{R^3}\frac{\rho(\mathbf x')}{|\mathbf x-\mathbf x'|}\,d^3x'
=-4π\int_0^\infty\frac{\rho(r')}{|r-r'|}r'^2\,dr'$ ,

and I am failing.

Here is my code to check the $\gamma=2$ case:

```
Assuming[{r > 0, g == 2}, -4 π Integrate[
   s^(-g) / Abs[r - s] s^2, {s, 0, ∞}]]
```

Mathematica gives me the message: "Integrate: Integral of 1/Abs[r-s] does not converge on {0,[Infinity]}"

My code for the other case is

```
Assuming[{r > 0, g != 2, g < 3}, -4 π Integrate[
   s^(-g) / Abs[r - s] s^2, {s, 0, ∞}]]
```

which also yields "Integrate: Integral of s^(2-g)/Abs[r-s] does not converge on {0, ∞}."

What am I missing?

Comment: One does problems of this sort with the help of the  Gauss theorem. The way you try it, is much too difficult, and directly it will not work.

Comment: Hi @AlexeiBoulbitch , thanks for the answer! Sure, there might be simpler ways than directly evaluating the integral. I wanted to try this, since later I want to generalise this to more complex distributions and integrate numerically. But I found a mistake now: I cannot simply replace $|\mathbf x-\mathbf x'|$ in the 3D integrand by $|r-r'|$ in the 1D integrand! I will correct this and try again tomorrow and then report back!

Comment: `FullSimplify[Integrate[s^(2-g)/Sqrt[(r-s)^2],s]]` does this help? You can now try `Limit` and `Series` with `Assuming`.

Comment: @Britzel If your (more complex) distributions are spherically- or cylindrically symmetric, the Gauss theorem approach is the way to implement. Do you know it? If you have an asymmetric problem you will have a bad time. I am just struggling against a comparable problem, where I need to integrate a Green function over a distribution. [Here][1] you can see the level of mathematical difficulties arising there. Have fun! 


  [1]: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215614/a-suitable-strategy-to-estimate-numerically-a-complex-integral-how-to-use-maxe/215698#215698

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch For the start they will be spherically symmetric, yes. Perhaps it is a good idea to go with a Gauß theorem approach for now, as you suggest. Eventually though they will become axisymmetric. But not for now.

Comment: As much as I remember, for the gravitation case, the Gauss theorem states: `Flux=4*Pi*G*M`. Here G is the gravitational constant, `Flux` is the gravitational flux through a spherical surface of radius R, `Flux=4*Pi*R^2*g`, g is the gravity acceleration, M is the mass within the sphere. You get M by a simple integration: `M = Integrate[r^-\[Gamma]*4 \[Pi]*r^2, {r, 0, R0}]`. Done.

Comment: Indeed I was working it out Gauß style then. Thanks again @AlexeiBoulbitch 
!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with the expansion: to integrate $\frac{1}{\lvert \mathbf{x'} - \mathbf{x}\rvert}$ over a volume with a spherically invariant factor (the charge density), the standard (and the most sensible trick) is to apply spherical harmonic decomposition:

> $$\frac{1}{\lvert \mathbf{x'} - \mathbf{x}\rvert}=\sum\limits_{l=0}^\infty\frac{r_<^l}{r_>^{l+1}}\left(\frac{4\pi}{2l+1}\right)\sum\limits_{m=-l}^{l}Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)Y_{lm}^*(\theta',\phi')$$

With this expansion, the integral will be much simpler; in particular, the angular integral will immediately fix radial dependence. In fact, for spherically symmetric overall factor, the angular integration simply reads

> $$\begin{align}
> \int d\Omega'\rho(r')\frac{1}{\lvert \mathbf{x'} - \mathbf{x}\rvert}=&\sum\limits_{l=0}^\infty\frac{r_<^l}{r_>^{l+1}}\left(\frac{4\pi}{2l+1}\right)\sum\limits_{m=-l}^{l}Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)\rho(r')\int d\Omega'Y_{lm}^*(\theta',\phi')\\
> =&\sum\limits_{l=0}^\infty\frac{r_<^l}{r_>^{l+1}}\left(\frac{4\pi}{2l+1}\right)\sum\limits_{m=-l}^{l}Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)\rho(r')\sqrt{4\pi}\delta_l^0\delta_m^0\\
> =&\frac{4\pi}{r_>}\rho(r')
> \end{align}$$

The radial integral is now straightforward:

> $$\begin{align}
> \int d^3x'\frac{\rho(r')}{\lvert \mathbf{x'} - \mathbf{x}\rvert}=&\int r'^2 dr'\int d\Omega'\rho(r')\frac{1}{\lvert \mathbf{x'} - \mathbf{x}\rvert}\\
> =&4\pi\int \rho(r')r' dr'\\
> =&4\pi\int r'^{1-\gamma} dr'
> \end{align}$$

which yields your expected result.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! I will have to look back into spherical harmonics in order to understand the angular integration you performed. Will do so now!

Comment: Soner, can you show how you did this with the Wolfram Language?

Comment: @CATrevillian I am unaware of how to do intermediate steps I wrote above with the Wolfram Language.