# StepSize of Nintegration

Tags: numerical-integration

```
NIntegrate[Sin[Sin[x]], {x, 0, 2}]
```

Is there information regarding the stepsize of x in the range from 0 to 2?

Comment: Have you already seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96663)?

Comment: It usually uses adaptive sampling to reduce the error estimate to an acceptable level.  You might want to review the introductions in this set of tutorials: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateOverview.html. You'll see `NIntegrate` is quite complicated. After reading the introductions, you might dip into subsections that interest you. For instance, the usual **strategy** chosen is called `"GlobalAdaptive"`.