# NIntegrate results different when using 0 or 0.0

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics

i was trying to compute a convolution numerically, but got unexpected results. In the end i was able to reduce it to the code below. As you can see, the results are different, depending on whether i write (0-x)^2, x^2 or (0.0-x)^2 (x is a real value). i have Mathematica 10.3.
can somebody explain that to me?
thank you very, very much for your help.
all my best wishes
esra

```
(*  In[77]:=  *)
NIntegrate[
 0.16076649110325864` E^(-9774.602659078126` Sqrt[    x^2]) (Erfc[-123.28828005937953` Sqrt[10^-4] + 
      10 Sqrt[110/7] Sqrt[x^2/10^-4]] - 
    E^(19549.20531815625` Sqrt[x^2])
      Erfc[123.28828005937953` Sqrt[10^-4] + 
       10 Sqrt[110/7] Sqrt[x^2/10^-4]]) ((
    3 (0 - x)^2)/(0.000025` + (0 - x)^2)^(5/2) - 
    1/(0.000025` + (0 - x)^2)^(3/2)), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]

(*  Out[77]= -410.318  *)

(*  In[84]:=  *)
NIntegrate[
 0.16076649110325864` E^(-9774.602659078126` Sqrt[    x^2]) (Erfc[-123.28828005937953` Sqrt[10^-4] + 
      10 Sqrt[110/7] Sqrt[x^2/10^-4]] - 
    E^(19549.20531815625` Sqrt[x^2])
      Erfc[123.28828005937953` Sqrt[10^-4] + 
       10 Sqrt[110/7] Sqrt[x^2/10^-4]]) ((
    3 (0.0 - x)^2)/(0.000025` + (0.0 - x)^2)^(5/2) - 
    1/(0.000025` + (0.0 - x)^2)^(3/2)), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]

(*  Out[84]= -205.159  *)

(*  In[78]:=  *)
NIntegrate[
 0.16076649110325864` E^(-9774.602659078126` Sqrt[    x^2]) (Erfc[-123.28828005937953` Sqrt[10^-4] + 
      10 Sqrt[110/7] Sqrt[x^2/10^-4]] - 
    E^(19549.20531815625` Sqrt[x^2])
      Erfc[123.28828005937953` Sqrt[10^-4] + 
       10 Sqrt[110/7] Sqrt[x^2/10^-4]]) ((3 x^2)/(0.000025` + x^2)^(
    5/2) - 1/(0.000025` + x^2)^(3/2)), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]

(*  Out[78]= -410.318  *)
```

Comment: Add `AccuracyGoal->10`  inside `NIntegrate`and Mathematica evaluates all the integrals to  `zero`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann That certainly solves the problem of inconsistency! :)

Comment: Close voters: On the face of it, I would have predicted no difference. I don't see the "simple mistake" or how it's explained in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

This might be considered a bug, but the behavior of `NIntegrate` follows the `"GlobalAdaptive"` strategy.  The integral, in fact, exposes a weakness in the strategy.

With the exact form with `(0 - x)^2`, `NIntegrate` takes advantage of the symmetry to multiply the integrand by `2` and integrate over `{0, Infinity}`.

With the inexact form with `(0.0 - x)^2`, `NIntegrate` does not recognize the symmetry and integrates over `{-Infinity, Infinity}`. At first, the interval is split in half, at `x == 0`. The integrand underflows to zero at all sampling points in each interval, yielding estimates of `0.` for the integral and error. The precision and accuracy goals cannot be met if the integral is zero and we have `AccuracyGoal -> Infinity`. In such a case, `NIntegrate` will try a couple of subdivisions, as long as the integral and error remain zero, before returning `0.` and giving a `NIntegrate::izero` warning. In the OP’s case, `NIntegrate` first tries this on `{0, Infinity}`.  After the first subdivision, the integral and error estimate turn out to be `1.70951*10^-109` (both, that is 100% error) instead of zero.

We now have a new situation:

- The total integral is positive, `1.70951*10^-109`.
- The error over the negative reals is `0.`.
- The relative error is 100%, so further subdivisions will be carried out on the interval with the greatest error.

In the `"GlobalAdaptive"` strategy, the further subdivisions will never subdivide the integral over the negative reals because it will always have the smallest error estimate. Therefore, `NIntegrate` will calculate the integral over `{0, Infinity}` accurately as with the exact form, but it will accept `0.` for the integral over `{-Infinity, 0}`. So the value of the integral is exactly half of what it should be.

This analysis suggests other workarounds:

```
NIntegrate[integrand, {x, -Infinity, Infinity},
 Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]

NIntegrate[integrand, {x, -Infinity, Infinity},
 MinRecursion -> 4]

(*  -410.318  *)
```

Note that if `AccuracyGoal -> ag` is set so that `ag < Accuracy[0.]`, `NIntegrate` will return `0.` for the integral.  Note `Accuracy[0.] == -Log10@$MinMachineNumber + $MachinePrecision`, which is about `323.6`.

I said this might be considered a bug, although the behavior fits exactly with the global adaptive strategy.  One could imagine that `NIntegrate` might be improved by subdividing any interval over which the integral is zero, or giving a warning whenever it encounters such an interval.  If it had done it once, the error estimate would have been extremely small `10^-109` compared to the rest of the integral. Probably the intervals would not have been subdivided further, and the integral would still be only `-205`.  The question then is when should `NIntegrate` give up subdividing? It's not so easy to fix in a way that is efficient.

This analysis was carried out with the help of the [IntegrationMonitor](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26401/determining-which-rule-nintegrate-selects-automatically/96663#96663) option.  For instance:

```
NIntegrate[integrand, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 IntegrationMonitor :> ((Print@
      Thread[Through[#["OriginalBoundaries"]] -> 
        Through[#["Error"]]]) &)]
```

---

*Original guesses*

The main difficulty is the effective support of $f$ where $|f(x)| >\mkern-4mu> 0$ is so small compared to the scale `NIntegrate` expects.

Here are some hypotheses that I won't have time to fully explore:

It could be a numerics thing, since `0.0` might demote the function value to `MachinePrecision`, whereas `0` would not.  When `NIntegrate` has to make small subdivisions, it increases the precision of the variable.  The presence of other machine-precision constants should have a similar, but perhaps not exactly the same, effect.  This casts doubt on this hypothesis, but it's the only hypothesis I have at this point that accounts for the difference in the value of the integral.

Or, given that the integrals are off by a factor of almost exactly 2, it could be a preprocessing thing, probably `"EvenOddSubdivision"` since the integrand is an even function. The difference between how the integrands are processed might still be explained by a numerics issue.

Some fixes, each of which focus in on the effective support of the integrand:

```
NIntegrate[f[x], {x, -Infinity, -1/10, 1/10, Infinity}]

NIntegrate[f[x],
 {x, -Infinity, 0, Infinity}, 
 Method -> {"PrincipalValue", 
   "SingularPointIntegrationRadius" -> 10^-1}]
```

The correct value seems to be  `-410.318`.

Another fix that "corrects" the numerics issue, whatever it may be:

```
NIntegrate[SetPrecision[f[x], 17],
 {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

*Update:*
After looking at Bob's answer, setting precision essentially does the same thing: that is, both cause `0.0` to become `0`.  As a "fix," it may not seem much, since it's easier to write `0` to begin with.  But if the integrands are not written but generated programmatically, then rationalizing or raising the precision is probably the easiest way to go.  It doesn't take care of a very small interval of support though.

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

expr = 0.16076649110325864` E^(-9774.602659078126` Sqrt[
       x^2]) (Erfc[-123.28828005937953` Sqrt[10^-4] + 
       10 Sqrt[110/7] Sqrt[x^2/10^-4]] - 
     E^(19549.20531815625` Sqrt[x^2]) Erfc[
       123.28828005937953` Sqrt[10^-4] + 
        10 Sqrt[110/7] Sqrt[x^2/10^-4]]) ((3 x^2)/(0.000025` + x^2)^(5/2) - 
     1/(0.000025` + x^2)^(3/2));

f[expr_] := NIntegrate[expr, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]

f[expr]

(* -410.318 *)

f[expr /. x^2 :> (0 - x)^2]

(* -410.318 *)

f[expr /. x^2 :> (0.0 - x)^2]

(* -205.159 *)
```

[`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) prior to substitution doesn't resolve the issue

```
f[Rationalize[expr] /. x^2 :> (0.0 - x)^2]

(* -205.159 *)
```

`Rationalize` after substitution does resolve the issue

```
f[Rationalize[expr /. x^2 :> (0.0 - x)^2]]

(* -410.318 *)
```

Also note that in this case if you want to remove all real values. `Rationalize[expr, 0]` is required.