# Why can I not numerically integrate a smooth, integrable function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, warning-messages, trigonometry

Consider the function $\csc(t)\sin(3t)$ on the interval $[0,\pi]$. This is a perfectly well-behaved smooth function, as can be seen when plotting it:

```
Plot[2 Csc[t] Sin[3 t], {t, 0, π}]
```

so why cannot I not numerically integrate it by running the following?

```
NIntegrate[2 Csc[t] Sin[3 t], {t, 0, π}]
```

Instead I get the error message "NIntegrate::errprec: Catastrophic loss of precision in the global error estimate due to insufficient WorkingPrecision or divergent integral". FYI I expect the answer to be $2\pi$, as can be seen by running

```
Integrate[2 Csc[t] Sin[3 t], {t, 0, π}]
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Round-off error (from the asymptotes of `Csc[t]`). Following the advice in the error message, try it wth `WorkingPrecision -> 16`.

Comment: Or try `NIntegrate[2 Csc[t] Sin[3 t] // TrigExpand, {t, 0, \[Pi]}]`

Comment: In some sense, `NIntegrate` selects a bad rule (Clenshaw-Curtis osciilatory).  Try `NIntegrate[2 Csc[t] Sin[3 t], {t, 0, \[Pi]}, Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"]`

Comment: Or use `Integrate` rather than `NIntegrate`

Comment: I am certain this is a toy example, but for the integral as presented by the OP, reformulating the integrand does the trick: `NIntegrate[2 ChebyshevU[2, Cos[t]], {t, 0, π}]`

Comment: @J.M.:  So does applying `TrigExpand` to the Integrand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe my last comment makes it worth posting my comments as an answer. The first one shows that the error message contains a hint at a fix, and one naturally would try it out first. The second one seems a common-sense thing to try. For the last one I had to take [a look into what `NIntegrate` was doing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96663/4999).

> Round-off error (from the asymptotes of `Csc[t]`). Following the advice in the error message, try it wth `WorkingPrecision -> 16`. –
> Michael E2
> 18 mins ago

> Or try `NIntegrate[2 Csc[t] Sin[3 t] // TrigExpand, {t, 0, \[Pi]}]` –
> Michael E2
> 9 mins ago

> In some sense, NIntegrate selects a bad rule (Clenshaw-Curtis oscillatory). Try `NIntegrate[2 Csc[t] Sin[3 t], {t, 0, \[Pi]}, Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"]` –
> Michael E2
> 52 secs ago

`Method -> "LevinRule"` also works.

Comment: Does anyone have a reference for how `Method -> "ClenshawCurtisOscillatoryRule"` works?  I assume the catastrophic loss of precision comes from some sort of extrapolation to the endpoints where the integrand is undefined (not from a catastrophic loss in `Csc[t]` per se, which is improbable).

Comment: If memory serves, that one is supposed to be an implementation of the method of Piessens and Branders, first noted [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/0771-050X(75)90033-9), and then extended [here](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01934465).

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for the references.