# Simple numerical integral takes forever to compute

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm trying to compute a fairly simple numerical integral, but it seems to take forever to compute:

```
f[s_, t_] :=  0.4714 *Exp[-0.6666*I *s + 0.3333*I*t] + 0.4714*Exp[-1.66666*I*s + 1.33333*I*t]
NIntegrate[f[s, t]^3, {s, 0, 2*Pi}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

If I remove the decimal places, to

```
f[s_, t_] :=  0.4 *Exp[-0.6*I *s + 0.3*I*t] + 0.4*Exp[-1.6*I*s + 1.3*I*t]
NIntegrate[f[s, t]^3, {s, 0, 2*Pi}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

then it computes in about a second (which still seems quite slow?). But howcome it takes so much longer for the first integral? I am missing something. Perhaps my pc is out of resources.

Answer (score 2):

```
NIntegrate[f[s, t]^3, {s, 0, 2*Pi}, {t, 0, 2*Pi},Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]  
(*{0.0707075, 6.49829*10^-8 + 1.78683*10^-11 I}*)
```

evaluates immideatly.

By the way it is good praxis to use symbolic parameter values if possible:

```
f[s_, t_] :=0.4714*Exp[-2/3*I*s + 1/3*I*t] + 0.4714*Exp[-5/3*I*s + 4/3*I*t] //Rationalize[#, 0] &
NIntegrate[f[s, t]^3, {s, 0, 2*Pi}, {t, 0, 2*Pi},Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]  
(*-2.80592*10^-16 - 2.21828*10^-16 I*)
```

Integral equals (numerical) zero!

```
Integrate[f[s, t]^3, {s, 0, 2*Pi}, {t, 0, 2*Pi} ]
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: Thank you. Seems strange it doesn't try something like  "LocalAdaptive" by default in this case. I don't know what it's doing but it feels like the default behaviour shouldn't struggle on this integral.

Comment: @BruceBartlett "I don't know what it's doing but it feels like the default behaviour shouldn't struggle on this integral." -- **1)** Zero value integrals are simply not that important. **2)** In order to see the strategy and rule selected by `NIntegrate` you can try following [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96663/34008).

Comment: Including the option `AccuracyGoal -> Automatic` also leads to a quick evaluation.

Comment: Many thanks for these tips.