# Get current integral value in NIntegrate's EvaluationMonitor

Tags: numerical-integration, dynamic

Is it possible to display the current evaluation result while NIntegrate[] is running?

Something like this:

```
Dynamic[c];
NIntegrate[f[x],{x,0,1},EvaluationMonitor :>(*assign current value of NIntegrate[] to c*)]
```

Let's say NIntegrate calls

```
f[0]=1
c=1
f[.1]=2
c=1.5
f[.4]=3
c=2
f[.7]=-1
c=1.25
...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96663) already?

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find there what I am looking for - or don't understand it. The method there seems to only give information about every integration region after it is done. But I am looking for the final result of the integration with it's current current uncertainty.

Comment: By current uncertainty, do you mean error bound? (That is not what you asked for. Rather you seem to have wanted something like `IntegrationMonitor -> ((c = Total@Through[#@"Integral"]) &)`.)

Comment: For the error bound, perhaps this?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/106170/4999

Comment: Thank you very much, I missed Total@Through[#@"Integral"]. That's not exactly what I was looking for, but it's just as good to see what's going on.